# How can I make this code find amicable numbers in a determined range in javaScript?

Tags: javascript

I want to have a code that finds amicable numbers in a certain range, but it only outputs one amicable number instead of all amicable numbers in that range.

How can I solve it? I think it may be a scope error.

> Amicable numbers are a pair of numbers that the sum of all the divisors of the first number equals the second number, and the sum of the divisors of the second number equals the first number.

Here is my code:

```
let sum1 = 1;
let sum2 = 1;

for (let num1 = 3; num1 < 1300; num1++) {
    for (let num2 = 3; num2 < 1300; num2++) {

        for (let div1 = 2; div1 < num1; div1++) {
            if (num1 % div1 === 0) {
                sum1 += div1
            }
        }

        for (let div2 = 2; div2 < num2; div2++) {
            if (num2 % div2 === 0) {
                sum2 += div2
            }
        }


        if (num1 === sum2 && sum1 === num2) {
            console.log(num1 + " and " + num2 + " are amicable numbers!")

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is very inefficient, having to calculate the sum of the divisors on every iterartion - even though you have previously calculated the sum of divisors for this number.

I tend to find it easier to think about this sort of problem in multiple steps. Step 1, calculate the sum of divisors for any given number:

```
const sumDivisors = num => {
  let res = 0;
  for(let i=1;i<num;i++)
    if( (num % i) == 0)
      res += i
  return res;
}
```

Step 2, gather the numbers in the desired range and all their sums of divisors

```
var divisors = new Array(1300).fill(0).map( (_,i) => i)
                              .reduce( (acc,num) => ({...acc, [num]: sumDivisors(num)}))
```

The above gives you an object with `num` as the key and `sum` (of divisors) as the value.

```
{
  "1": 0,
  "2": 1,
  "3": 1,
  "4": 3,
  "5": 1,
  "6": 6,
  "7": 1,
  "8": 7,
    .. etc
}
```

Step3, look for any item in the list where

- key less than value (this also covers key != value and stops you getting both ways in the result ie 220,284 & 284,220)
- value matches another key

Put it all together you get the below code which gives the expected results

```js
const sumDivisors = num => {
  let res = 0;
  for(let i=1;i<num;i++)
    if( (num % i) == 0)
      res += i
  return res;
}

var divisors = new Array(1300).fill(0).map( (_,i) => i)
                              .reduce( (acc,num) => ({...acc, [num]: sumDivisors(num)}))
var amicable = Object.entries(divisors)
                     .filter( ([num,sum]) => num < sum && divisors[sum] == num);

for(let [num1,num2] of amicable)
  console.log(num1 + " and " + num2 + " are amicable numbers!")
```

You may like to compare the performance difference here between your original code (fixed to work) and the code in this answer: https://jsbench.me/jekosj89v4/1 The improvement in speed is a factor of 1000

Comment: Thank you very much! I still need many centuries of practice, I'm pretty new to this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your code is never resets the sums so it will never find a match.

I don't know how to make it very efficient because I don't know about complexity, but here is my algorithm:

First, export the sum of dividers to a function so we can use it for any given number.

Then, loop through the numbers up to 1300 for example and use the function to find the sum of dividers for each number. When you have the sum, this is the number you want to check backwards (if the sum dividers of that number is equal to the original number they are amicable pair), you don't have to check all the numbers because the sum of dividers will give you only one number.

If the sum of dividers is less than the number, we already checked it and found the pair. If the number is equal to the sum it is the same number, this is not a pair.

So this is my final code:

```js
const getDividersSum = (num) => {
  let sum = 0;
  for (let i = 1; i <= num / 2; i++) {
    if (num % i === 0) {
      sum += i;
    }
  }
  return sum;
}

for (let num = 3; num < 1300; num++) {
  const amicableNum = getDividersSum(num);
  if (amicableNum !== num && num < amicableNum) {
    if (getDividersSum(amicableNum) === num) {
      console.log('Amicable nums: ', num, amicableNum);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Great answer, and more efficient still than mine: https://jsbench.me/jekosj89v4/2

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to move the declarations of `sum1` and `sum2` inside the second for loop. Check out [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/BlueMtn16/jxLwefdq/). (Edit: reason is because the sums continue to grow rather than resetting each time.)

Note, I changed a bit of code to ensure that the numbers were distinct (see `num1 !== num2` on line 18 of the fiddle) and to avoid repeated pairs (see `num2 < num1` rather than `num2 < 1300` on line 2 of the fiddle.)